# Intellij is not providing either popup or menu options to run a scalatest created by Intellij itself

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I am uncertain why a given *scala* project is not being identified as *scalatest* - capable/ready..

Actually it has been possible to generate new *ScalaTest*'s by hitting the Shift-Command-T . But then I can not *run* them..

[image]

The dialog shows that `ScalaTest` is healthy:

[image]

And a correct `ScalaTest`-ready class is generated:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class MetricUtilsTest extends FunSuite {

  test("testF") {

  }

  test("testError") {

  }

}
```

However there is *no popup or menu option* to allow to  *run/debug* the test from within IJ:

[image]

*Things I have tried*

- Delete the Intellij project and start from scratch
- Multiple different test suites (none are able to be run)

Note that the newly created test ***does run from command line*** (which shows us the *maven* project is healthy):

```
 mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com/blazedb/spark/MetricUtilsTest.scala -Dexec.args=""
```

***Update*** I am able to ***manually*** set up a *Run Configuration* for the newly created test *and run the test* successfully.

[image]

So.. *what is going on with the popup menu not working here* ?  I am on `Ultimate 2019.1` .

Comment: what version do you have? It works for me with Ultimate 2019.1

Comment: _version_   likewise on `Ultimate 2019.1` (downloaded last week)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!  Somehow the following (non default I presume?) setting got selected:

[image]

**I do not ever use *gradle*** so not sure how/when that got set.. The obvious fix is to reset this to *Platform Test Runner* :

[image]

And *voila'* we're back to the expected pop-up dialog including the options to *Run/Debug* current *scalatest* :

[image]

Note that this problem was diagnosed by using the *Actions* search dialog (shift-command-A) and typing "Run Test"

Comment: ah you use Gradle - that's the difference;)

Comment: I do _not_ use gradle: and am uncertain how that got mixed up in all this. I had mentioned in the answer: now I'll *bold* it  ;)